# Enable TextBox when ListViewItem is selected in WPF (databinding)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, binding, textbox

How can i enable/disable a TextBox with DataBinding in WPF when a ListViewItem is (not) selected?

I have created a converter class:

```
public class BoolConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

and added the property to the TextBox:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listViewCards, Converter={StaticResource BoolConvert}}"
```

but i have a XamlParseException becouse he can´t find the class :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could alternately use a style trigger on the TextBox, eliminating the need for a ValueConverter:

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
       <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lvItems, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
         </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
<ListView Name="lvItems" .../>
```

Comment: The TextBox will be enabled when you start debugging until the SelectedItem is set on the ListView.  Are you trying to do the opposite, where the TextBox is enabled only when something is selected in the ListView?

Comment: exactly *sry* 
TextBox should only enabled if something is selected at the ListView :-)

Comment: no problem; If you reverse the True / False Values from the two Setters in my XAML sample I think you'll get the result your looking for.  Since the TextBox is enabled by default, you could actually remove the first Setter in the style completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the `IsEnabled` property on the `TextBox` to the `SelectedItem` property on the `ListView`. Then you'll need a converter (an implementation of `IValueConverter`) to convert selected values into boolean values.

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listView, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
<ListView x:Name="listView" .../>
```

Then, in your converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, ...)
{
    return value == null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ListViewItem in ListView :

Enable if Selected.
Try the following:

```
<ListViewItem Margin="5" Background="AliceBlue">
    <TextBox Margin="5" Text="Lösung SECHS" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
</ListViewItem>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with UWP, which has no FindAncestor?